# Images not appearing in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, joomla

I'm having trouble with some images on Internet Explorer. They show on other browsers but not in IE. I just get the area where the images should be with an X inside the box.

Here is the URL: http://www.myramis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=56

Hope someone can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: Looked at the page in IE9 and I can see all the images.

Comment: Have you just changed something? Because it works fine now and didn't a minute ago… image format problem maybe? Wrong extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image is most likely saved in CMYK instead of RGB-mode

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing PNG image transparency replacement for IE and the transparent.gif (or x.gif) or whatever it's called is not in the correct path? Probably explains why I am seeing the infamous light blue background instead of the transparency for the images in IE6 :-)

Comment: hi, the particular image I'm referring to is a jpg so there is no transparency being used.

Comment: Hi it is no longer missing now, I've fixed the problem thanks to the response below, I appreiate your comments.

Comment: Heh, I just read that @Lasse solved your problem :-) +1 for @Lasse